# Can one of these be true and the other one be false?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\forall y \in A, \exists x \in B, M(y) \rightarrow N(x) \\
(\forall y \in A, M(y)) \rightarrow (\exists x \in B, N(x))$

From what I understand, it's not possible for the first statement to be False and the second statement to be True but is the opposite possible?

Comment: What do you mean by $M(y)\implies N(x)$ here? As written, the first statement is saying some rather 'odd' things — you should be able to break it into smaller chunks, one of which must be true, and then see how those compare to the things that the second statement is saying.

Comment: I am assuming a typo, where, in the 2nd statement, $P(y)$ is supposed to equate with $M(y)$ in the first statement. 
 Based on this assumption, the first statement is a stronger statement, which could be false, when the 2nd statement is true.  The 2nd statement is saying that the implication only holds if every element $y \in A$ satisfies $P(y)$.  What if **almost** all of the elements $y \in A$ satisfy $P(y)$, but there is at least one element $y \in A$ that does not satisfy $P(y)$?  What are the resulting implications in statement 1 versus statement 2?

Comment: There is also a subtle difference between the two statements that is not pertinent to your question.  In statement 1, the choice of $x$ could vary with the choice of $y$.  That is, you could have that if $P(y_1)$, then $N(x_1)$, while if $P(y_2)$, then $N(x_2)$.  In statement 2, it is as if there exists at least one element  $x \in B$ that is a sort of universal $x$, which is only implied if every $y \in A$ satisfies $P(A)$.  As I say, this *wrinkle* isn't really pertinent to the question that you asked.

Comment: Hint: What can we say about the case where one formula or the other is false?